# Communicate between custom directives in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and working on creating tabs in a page. Till now I have resolved my problems with angularjs by searching a lot on internet but I can't resolve this. Hope anyone can help me with ideas and better knowledge of angularjs.

I have two custom directives tabset and tab. 'Tabset' is the directive to maintain the tabs and 'tab' is for a single tab.

```
  app.directive('tabset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'tabset.html',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.tabs = [];
      this.addTab = function(tab) {
        $scope.tabs.push(tab);
      }
       console.log("In tabset controller");
    },
    link : function(scope){
      console.log("In the tabset link");
    }
  } 
});

//Custom Directive for the tab controls
app.directive('tab', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h2>Welcome to Stackoverflow</h2> <div role="tabpanel" ng-transclude></div>',
    require : '^tabset',
    scope: {},
    link : function(scope, elem, attr, tabsetCntrl) {  
      tabsetCntrl.addTab(scope);
      console.log("In the tab link");
    }
  }
});
```

I call these directives in my HTML page as shown below:

```
<tabset>
     <tab>
        This is one tab
     </tab>
     <tab>
        This is another tab
     </tab>
</tabset>
```

But, when I run the code, the link function of the tab directive is not running. The 'require : ^tabset' option gets the controller from the tabset, but the link function of the tab directive is not working.

Comment: Maybe try adding a `controllerAs: '$ctrl',` to the `tabset` directive definition?  

Seen in [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/noident?p0=tabset)

Comment: Can you put the plunker ?

Comment: Got it bro @Gary. Actually the code is correct. There was a problem with the version. The older versions of angularJs doesn't support ngTransclude as an element.

Comment: Ouch. That was nasty. Cool

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `controllerAs: '$ctrl'` to your tabset directive.

Like:

```
angular.module('app').directive('tabset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'tabset.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl', // <---- HERE
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.tabs = [];
      this.addTab = function(tab) {
        $scope.tabs.push(tab);
      }
       console.log("In tabset controller");
    },
    link : function(scope){
      console.log("In the tabset link");
    }
  } 
});
```

[Tested](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyXvEjPp1wRPe6BAewxo?p=preview)

---

Further info found by checking the error seen in console [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/noident?p0=tabset)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Prudhvee, take a look at this demo i did to understand the making of angular tabs using nested directives.

```
app.directive('tabset', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {},
  controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
    var panes = $scope.panes = [];

    $scope.select = function(pane) {
      angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
        pane.selected = false;
      });
      pane.selected = true;
    }

    this.addPane = function(pane) {
      if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
      panes.push(pane);
    }
  }],
  template:
    '<div class="tabbable">' +
      '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
          '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>',
  replace: true
};
});
app.directive('tab', function() {
return {
  require: '^tabset',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: { title: '@' },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
    tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
  },
  template:
    '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
    '</div>',
  replace: true
 };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BJWWw2?p=preview

Comment: Thanks bro for the help.